# Gaussian distribution proof

Tags: probability

How can i show that the most likely variable (with the highest probability density) is also mean for p(x; mean, standard deviation) in a gaussian distribution? I know i somehow have to utilize the derivative being zero at the peak and that the peak of the log of the normal distribution has the same x value as the original. How do i go about proving this? I have already tried utilizing my assumptions but have not been successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording isn't very clear, but my assumption is that if you have a random variable $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, you wish to show that $f_{X}$ is maximized at $\mu$.

Consider that $$f_{X}(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\dfrac{1}{2}\left( \dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]$$
over $\mathbb{R}$. Instead of taking the derivative directly, note that wherever $f_{X}$ is maximized, $\ln f_{X}$ is maximized as well. Notice
$$\ln f_{X}(x) = -\ln(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})-\dfrac{1}{2}\left( \dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\text{.}$$
The derivative of $\ln f_{X}$ with respect to $x$ is 
$$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[ \ln f_{X}(x) \right]  = -\left(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right) = 0 \implies x = \mu\text{.}$$
To show that this is actually a maximum, you can show that the second derivative is negative, hence this is a maximum.